# Rails model function gets false when it's true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I have a model and a function in it to check if it's valid. The thing is that it's always returning false, even when it's true.

This is the function:

```
def is_valid?
  if self.active == true && (self.end_date.nil? || self.end_date >= Time.now)
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

And here is the console output:

```
1.9.2p320 :013 > sd.active == true
 => true 
1.9.2p320 :014 > sd.end_date.nil?
 => false 
1.9.2p320 :015 > sd.end_date >= Time.now
 => true 
1.9.2p320 :016 > (sd.end_date.nil? || sd.end_date >= Time.now)
 => true 
1.9.2p320 :017 > sd.active && (sd.end_date.nil? || sd.end_date >= Time.now)
 => true 
1.9.2p320 :018 > sd.is_valid? 
 => false 
1.9.2p320 :019 > sd
 => #<SubscriptionDiscount id: 1, title: "Prueba de descuento", code: "TEST1",     monthly_discount: #<BigDecimal:902f748,'0.1E2',9(18)>, yearly_discount: #<BigDecimal:902f4f0,'0.1E3',9(18)>, active: true, end_date: "2012-08-01 00:00:00", created_at: "2012-06-06 00:04:10", updated_at: "2012-06-08 21:57:06">
```

Why it doesn't work? I don't see it.

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by simplifying that

```
def is_valid?
  active? && (end_date.nil? || end_date >= Time.now)
end
```

Does it still blow app?

If yes, put the following:

```
def is_valid?
  p active?
  p end_date.nil?
  p end_date >= Time.now
  active? && (end_date.nil? || end_date >= Time.now)
end
```

And share the output.

Comment: I did what you said and it didn't worked. I changed the name of the function and it worked. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You should still refactor the function as I suggested :)

Comment: I did, because you're right it's better that way. But the problem was solved by changing the name of the function.